# Get same name class from two application contexts in one class

Tags: java, spring

I tried searching the below question before posting here. I have experience in development in Spring but was unable to find answers myself and hence looking for help. 
This Question was asked to me in an interview.
Question is as follows.

**In your spring application, there are two different contexts And both the contexts are totally different and disconnected. Treat them as a complete separate application. Both the contexts have a class defined with same name. In one of your classes, you want to use the classes from both contexts. How will you differentiate between these two classes?**

Comment: you mean you have two classes with the same names? by using their paths/packages

Comment: With packaging ? com.my.This.class and com.yours.This.class

Comment: yeah, different package but same class name.

Comment: You shouldn't do that, class name should be changed!
Bad habits...

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz it was a question in an interview. So they may ask hypothetical questions.

Comment: Interview... everythink is clear. Yeah, package name, grettings!